# Migrate an adobe account (Certificates to build)

Tags: phonegap-build

Im having this issue today, we developed some apps years ago, with an adobe id from one of our developers. The person who own the account doesnt work with us anymore, so we are trying to migrate the account, just for the certificates we have there (apple and google) , cause i dont think we have the source files of those certificates.

Anyone had this issue in the past? Any idea how can we resolve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one - I'd recommend creating a "company" Adobe account going forward so that you don't run into this again.

Beyond contacting that user for access, perhaps log a support request with Adobe.

Even with that option though, there's no way to download the keys/certs from PG Build, so your best bet is to obtain them from the source - your Apple Developer and Google Play Developer accounts.